# Не сохраняются куки на mac os chrome

Tags: python, django, cookie

Создал веб приложение(http://warkb.pythonanywhere.com), в котором можно авторизоваться через VK, и которое сохраняет id зарегистрировавшегося в куки.

Приложение устроено таким образом, что после регистрации переход на url http://warkb.pythonanywhere.com автоматически перенаправляет пользователя на его страницу (http://warkb.pythonanywhere.com/userpage/[userid]).

На трех компьютерах, с операционной системой Windows 7/10 и браузерами vivaldi/chrome всё отлично работает. Но. У человека с Mac OS и браузером chrome куки не сохраняются. Притом, по уверениям этого человека, на других сайтах авторизация у него сохраняется.

Код сохранения куки прилагаю.

```
...
# запоминаем id пользователя в куках
response = HttpResponseRedirect('/userpage/%s' % user_id)
response.set_cookie(cookie_name, user_id)
return response
```

*Вопрос*: как сделать так, чтобы куки сохранялись? Может есть другой способ сохранения авторизации?

Comment: может быть связано: [Sending browser cookies during a 302 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4694089/4279)

Comment: Я попробовал добавить ещё одно добавление кук, уже в объект HttpResponse. Скинул ссылку человеку с маком, надеюсь заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том, что метод set_cookie вызывался у объекта HttpResponseRedirect, из-за чего куки игнорировались браузером клиента. После того, как я вместо этого объекта стал использовать объект HttpResponse, всё заработало.
P.S. Огромное спасибо пользователю jfs:"https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs" за помощь в решение проблемы